# Not able to achieve recursive stack-view in vmware clarity with angular

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm using [clarity](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/) with angular5.

I'm trying to achieve recursive [stack view](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/stack-view), but somehow `stack-view` is not considering dynamically generated `stack-blocks` as children, and hence view is not rendered properly.

```
<clr-stack-view>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stackBlockTemplate; context: {data: data}"></ng-container>
</clr-stack-view>
<ng-template #stackBlockTemplate let-data="data">
  <clr-stack-block *ngFor="let account of data">
    <clr-stack-content>Test - {{account.childAccounts ? account.childAccounts.length : 0}}</clr-stack-content>
    <ng-container *ngIf="account.childAccounts">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stackBlockTemplate; context: {data: account.childAccounts}"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </clr-stack-block>
</ng-template>
```

[image]

As you can see, I don't get a collapsible icon, because somehow `stack-view` is not considering dynamically generated `stack-block` as a child.

Here is **StackBlitz url**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v11-9bb9lg

Comment: Can you please post your data format of variable *data*?

Comment: Please reproduce your example in a StackBlitz, its hard to know what is happening without full details.

Comment: @JeremyWilken I updated answer with StackBlitz url